# SSRS Report Rendering Hangs With Stored Credentials For XML data source type

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportserver

In SSRS Report Server (SQL Server 2008 R2), I have a shared data source with data source type of XML. I have a report that uses a shared data set based off of the shared data source. The XML endpoint is living in an IIS-hosted Windows authentication app, and my development server is on a domain.

In Report Server, if I set the shared data source `Connect Using` option to `Windows integrated security`, the report renders quickly and as expected.

If I set `Connect Using` option to `Credentials stored securely in the report server` (with either domain or local account as configured account), the report rendering hangs indefinitely. There is no error. The "Loading... cancel" popup never goes away. The last line in the Report Server log file says:

```
library!ReportServer_0-6!19a4!11/22/2011-10:59:27:: i INFO: RenderForNewSession('/Test1/MyReportThatHangs')
```

Since Report Server caching does not work with `"Connect Using" = "Windows integrated security"`, I'd really like to use "Credentials stored securely in the report server". Is it possible that option is not supported with the XML data source type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was SSRS was trying to load BCMLogon.dll which it didn't have permission to.

For full thread, see here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/928cd523-9eeb-49ce-a145-e0885c76adba

> I guess I didn't wait long enough to get the error this guy did:
>   http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/01/network-provider-issues-and-sql-server.html
>   Renaming c:\windows\system32\BCMLogon.dll to BCMLogon-RENAMED.dll
>   fixed the problem (I'm working off of a Dell laptop). I can't believe
>   I didn't try that before...   Anyhow, I still think it's odd that
>   there was a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired
>   exception when checking "Impersonate the authenticated user after a
>   connection has been made to the data source" with an XML data source
>   (unless SqlDataClient has some mode where it can load XML from urls). 
>   Also, it seems that reporting services isn't properly notifying
>   clients that the HTTP request failed and instead leaves the client
>   hanging (but perhaps http.sys does not allow a response that after 15
>   minutes).